# Porn CMS with iframes

Tags: video, content-management-system

I'm looking for a CMS that can at least facilitate my work to create approximately 50k pages that contain code like:

```
<Iframe src = "http://link.com/embed/rewh3487432hdd" frameborder = "0" width = "608" height = "468" scrolling = "no"> </ iframe>
```

In addition to every video I have information such as the list of categories for each video (more than one for video), and tags that you would like to submit to me in some ways ..

I know that the request is quite general and will need to adapt the database to CMS, but would like to explore the possibility of avoiding me to generate the code to 0 ..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not exist.. I have watched forums, blogs and much articles, i have tryed Drupal, ClickBucket and Cumulusclips but all are good to upload the videos, but not for embedded videos.

Answer (score 0):

If using Drupal, you can simply put the iframe code as value of a text field, but make sure the text format is "Full HTML"

Here is an example of putting the iframe code into Body field of Basic page content type.

[image]